# How to show products to customer which is customer specific

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I need to have an idea how we can do the product to be visible to specific customer. Something like there are two customers when a product is assign to customer1 he could see the product when he is login and also the product should not be visible to the customer2.

Comment: is it for each individual customer or customer groups are there?

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV this is for each individual customer, can be for customer groups but for now each individual customer